# How to redirect to Tomcat depending on _escaped_fragment_ in the URL?

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, web-crawler, mod-jk

As part of trying to make an AJAX site crawlable, I wish to redirect URLs containing "_escaped_fragment_" to Tomcat.

I currently make Apache serve the root resource "/" but if the resource "/?_escaped_fragment_=" is requested then it should redirect the request to Tomcat so that the crawler servlet can service it.

It seems to me that you can not do that in mod_jk.conf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an Apache rewrite rule to transform the URL in a format that will be easier to forward to Tomcat using mod_jk:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(_escaped_fragment_=.*)
RewriteRule ^/$ /crawler/?%1 [L,R=permanent]
```

The above rule would only apply when the query string starts with `_escaped_fragment_=` and it will transform this URL:

```
http://host/?_escaped_fragment_=home
```

Into this one:

```
http://host/crawler/?_escaped_fragment_=home
```

You can then use the usual JkMount directive to forward `/crawler` to Tomcat, e.g.:

```
JkMount /crawler* ajp13_worker
```